# Shell Delete sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a file with some data like this:

```
1, 3, 0, 0, 0
0, 4, 5, 0, 5
2, 6, 0, 1, 0
```

I would like to write a shell script to delete all the lines where the 3rd argument is 0 (here line 1 and 2)

I already know that

```
sed -i '/0/d' file.txt
```

but I don't know how I can select the 3rd arguments whatever the others one.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Awk may be a better tool than sed for this task:

```
awk -F' *, *' '$3 != 0 {print}' FILE
```

But sed can do it:

```
sed -i '/^[0-9][0-9]*, [0-9][0-9]*, 0,/d' FILE
```

Comment: thanks awk is very good, how can I save the new data in a file?

Comment: @tranen: redirect the output with >. Or as you posted it, use -i for inplace when invoking sed.

Comment: @tranen: added `-i` usage to the example. Awk doesn't have that option, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -iE '/^([^,]+,){2} 0,/d' file
```

explained with [explain.py](https://github.com/vain/explain):

```
sed -iE '/^([^,]+,){2} 0,/d' file
\_/  ||  ||| || || \_/ | |
 |   ||  ||| || ||  |  | \- delete command
 |   ||  ||| || ||  |  |
 |   ||  ||| || ||  |  \- followed by blank zero komma
 |   ||  ||| || ||  |
 |   ||  ||| || ||  \- two times this inner pattern
 |   ||  ||| || ||
 |   ||  ||| || |\- followed by a comma
 |   ||  ||| || |
 |   ||  ||| || \- at least one of them
 |   ||  ||| ||
 |   ||  ||| |\- komma
 |   ||  ||| |
 |   ||  ||| \- not
 |   ||  |||
 |   ||  ||\- start of pattern, group of characters, which are
 |   ||  ||
 |   ||  |\- at begin of line
 |   ||  |
 |   ||  \- start of pattern for delete command
 |   ||
 |   |\- Extended regexp (parenthesis and braces without masking)
 |   |
 |   \- inplace changes
 |
 \- run sed
```

Answer (score 0):

awk with in place editing (similar to sed -i)

```
awk '$3!="0,"{print $0>FILENAME}' file
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -ane 'print unless $F[2]=="0," ' file
```